# Making one method contingent on another running successfully

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a situation where I need a service to have a few fields set before I can execute an HTTP call.  Those fields come from another HTTP call, so I can't run them asynchronously -- without that data, the second call will fail.  I think I have a way to do this, but I'm missing something -- the first method (`getSystemConfiguration()`) simply isn't firing, even though by the end of the chain there's definitely a `subscribe()` call.

I'm somewhat new to RxJs, so I feel like this should be simple, but what am I missing?

```
// Method that gets system configuration
setApiInformation(): Observable<void> {
    if (!this.apiKey || !this.checkUrl) {
        return this.systemConfigurationService.getSystemConfiguration()
            .pipe(
                map(config => {

                // None of this ever executes
                this.apiKey = config.apiKey;
                this.checkUrl = config.objectExistsUrl;
            }));
    } else {
        return of();
    }
}

// Method I'm trying to run
checkServerData(data: RequestParameters): Observable<ServerResponseData> {
    return this.setApiInformation()
        .pipe(map(() => {
            let httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ "serverApiKey" : this.apiKey }) };
            return this.httpClient.put<ServerResponseData>(this.checkUrl, request, this.httpOptions);
        }));
}

// Ultimate caller
let params: RequestParameters = { tenantId: 1, requestorId: 1 };
this.service.checkServerData(params)
   .subscribe((response: ServerResponseData) => { this.dataExists = response.success; });
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure that rxjs isn’t valid. You’ll need to use an actual operator inside your pipe

Comment: @bryan60 Good catch.  I wrapped it in a map, but now I'm being told that I'm returning Observable<Observable<ServerResponseData>>.  I've updated the post

Comment: I’ll fix it up in a few if no one gets it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few `rxjs` operators that can help you with this. i personally prefer `switchMap`. and this is how i would implement it:

```
this.setApiInformation().pipe(switchMap(data => {
  // do something here if needed
  return this.checkServerData();
})).subscribe( data => {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: It seems that switching from map() to swtichMap() did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

so, there's a couple things here. First, your observable chain has issues, you generally want to keep things INSIDE the observable sequence, and you want to do this in a repeatable fashion. I might rewrite this like so:

```
interface Config {
  apiKey: string
  checkUrl: string
}

@Injectable()    
export class MyService {
  private configSource = new ReplaySubject<Config>(1) // stores config

  private setApiInformation() { // private method to load config, call once
    this.systemConfigurationService.getSystemConfiguration().subscribe(this.configSource)
  }

  // all calls go through here to ensure config is ready
  private awaitConfig<T>(action$: (config: Config) => Observable<T>) {
    return this.configSource.pipe(
      first(),
      switchMap(client => action$(client)) // switchMap subscribes to inner observables
    )
  }

  constructor(private systemConfigurationService: SystemConfigurationService) {
    this.setApiInformation() // call once here
  }

  checkServerData(data: RequestParameters): Observable<ServerResponseData> {
    return this.awaitConfig(config => { // use config from here
      let httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ "serverApiKey" : config.apiKey }) };
      return this.httpClient.put<ServerResponseData>(config.checkUrl, request, this.httpOptions);
    }));
  }
}
```

This is a good way to solve this problem of all calls needing something asynchronous, you could in theory write a base service that the rest extend from or preferably inject and use to make their calls, BUT, if this is an app wide thing, you might be better served by using an APP_INITIALIZER to ensure something gets done (liek loading a config) before the rest of the application runs.

Comment: I see what you're doing.  My solution seems a lot more ham-handed, checking the values every time rather than just ensuring that the config was called once.  Part of it is I think I have an inherent aversion to constructors in Angular, since we use ngOnInit so often rather than relying on it.  My other problem (aside from the issue you caught in your original comment to my post) is that I needed to use switchMap().  Thanks for this solution!

Comment: ngOnInit is used in components more often than the constructor for one very important reason, which is that Input bindings aren't initialized until ngOnInit.  There's really no other reason to not be using the constructor. And never a reason to not use it in a service.

Comment: Also, I generally don't use ngOnInit as a matter of practice in services, but there's no reason you couldn't call the set function in ngOnInit if you really wanted to... go nuts

Comment: And you also have some more subtle synchronicity issues, where if the same config is needed by multiple clients at the same time, you will see it being requested multiple times